# UDID validation needed for iPhone XS ideviceinstaller using flutter - it is no longer 40 digits and has a dash in it

Tags: swift, flutter, libimobiledevice

I am working with libimobiledevice where whenever I am in need to push a bundle to iOS device with ideviceInstaller I am facing problem with iPhoneXR devices.
This problem is because of UDID : idevicepair without a UDID specified does work, but the problem is I have multiple devices connected to my machine.
 **ErrorMessage** :idevicepair -u *00008020-000625E#########*
idevicepair: invalid UDID specified (length != 40)
**Note:** I am using flutter to install the requirements like **Usbmuxd,libimobiledeivce and ideviceInstaller**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest version of libimobiledevice. If you're on Mac, try updating your version of libimobiledevice by running

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libimobiledevice
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies ideviceinstaller
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
brew install --HEAD ideviceinstaller
```